# Adding layout templates to WebSphere Portal theme ear

Tags: websphere-portal

**Question**: How do I refer to my layout files form the changeLayout.json and layout.json files if the layout-template files are held in a theme ear/ear?

**Background**:
I'm developing a custom theme with custom layouts in Portal v8. I'm using the ear method for the theme deployment,s o I've got everything segregated into MyThemeDynamic.war and MyThemeStatic.war I've added my layout files to MyThemeStatic.war/themes/MyTheme/layout-templates

When I set the default layout template in the XMLAccess import, I can successfully see my custom layout.
But If I try to change the layout, it reverts back to the Portal 8.0 theme defaults.
I've tried several ways of referring to my layout files from layout.json.

I saw this: http://tinyurl.com/ch2nczp
but it prevents the default theme from working properly, and I want to keep both the default and this new custom theme.

I've also tried adding references to the xml access, as suggested here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14909102&#14909102

I feel like I'm close, but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined static and dynamic theme assets into a single war file following these instructions:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Create_a_custom_theme_without_WebDAV_with_8.0

That was ultimately what worked.